# Error using scanf: return value ignored with floating point

Tags: c

this is my code and I'm not sure why I'm getting an error whenever I try to test it. It keeps saying return value ignored with scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void) {

    float money, tax, result;

    printf("Enter the amount of money.");
    scanf("%f", &money);

    tax = 0.05 * money;

    result = tax + money;

    printf("With tax added: $%f", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try for example to enter `abc` instead of a number when prompted, and see what happens next. That's one error case that checking the [return value of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) would catch.

Answer (score 5):

It is because return value is ignored.

You should check return values of `scanf()` to check if readings are successful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(void) {

    float money, tax, result;

    printf("Enter the amount of money.");
    if (scanf("%f", &money) != 1) {
        fputs("read error!\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    tax = 0.05 * money;

    result = tax + money;

    printf("With tax added: $%f", result);

    return 0;
}
```